# how to load the same user control with different condition in the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

how to load the same user control with different different condition in the same page for different different view.

i want to load a user control in the asp page in the 5 different different DIV, they have got a common view but different code behind that i can manage with the case statement at page load, i want to know how to make DIV know that for the same user control placed in the DIV what case to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a property in the usercontrol, which can be set either via the markup, or via the code in the codebehind.

For example...

```
private _myVar int = 0;
public int MyVar
{
   set { _myVar = value; }
}
```

Then you can set in the markup like...

```
<uc1:MyCtrl runat="sever" ID="ctrl1" MyVal="1"/>
```

Or in the codebhind you can...

```
ctrl.MyVar = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, @Novice, I hit the sumbit button before I'd finished